# Why is the internal rate of return decreasing while the profit per unit of real gross value added is increasing?

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, mathematical-economics, definition

I made a graph based on data from the [Penn World Table](https://www.rug.nl/ggdc/productivity/pwt/?lang=en) showing that the internal rate of return has been decreasing over time in the US and the rest of the G7 (even more if you exclude Germany, whose earlier statistics are not available and whose IRR increased since 2000 because its currency was undervalued and the PIIGS currencies overvalued when the Euro was introduced, which benefitted its export-dominated economy; a graph excluding Germany can also be found in this [spreadsheet](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ndy5f5ki1m3hl0l/G7+internal+rate+of+return+calculation.xlsx/file) where you can access the data behind this graph).

[image: Internal rate of return G7]

However, the profit per unit of real gross value added of nonfinancial corporate business in the US during the same time period increased rather drastically (graph can be accessed [here](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/A466RD3Q052SBEA)).

[image: profit per unit of real gross value added]

Can someone please explain to me the difference between these two statistics and why they would trend differently?